# Can OpenWRT serve with a switch and do IP filters and how?

Tags: networking, switch, openwrt

OpenWRT allows one to configure the switch on the router in many ways - do VLANs and similar.

However can OpenWRT behave like a switch but also do IP based filters - allow all traffic from port A to B and vice versa but block traffic from port A to some IP address and that would normally go to port B because the router/modem is there?

I need to block traffic to a particular IP address. The router/modem is too dumb to do firewall filtering. I cannot do NAT after the router because it needs direct access to the wifi points. Thus my only chance is to connect the wifi points to a switch that can do IP filtering from the traffic from the router/modem.

Comment: Linux supports filtering traffic on Ethernet bridges. Depending on your performance requirements this could be suitable.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of an example, intro, howto artice for this?

Comment: Sure we can help you. My comment implicitly contained the question what your performance expectations are. We also need to know the exact router model you have to propose the optimal configuration.

Comment: I understand that there will be performance hit. I can accept that. Packets will need to go through the CPU and the fast cirquitry of the switch will be virtually unused. Still I can dedicate a device for this.

Comment: For example MikroTik RB750Gr3 which is ~60 Euro. I will pay more if I will get faster connection - like going to 150 Euro is ok. The main requirement is that the device should have 2 usable ports and be fast invisible router. I would need some suggestion on device.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a device that has two “true” Ethernet interfaces. Some super cheap routers actually only have one Ethernet interface and use port-based VLANs on the built-in switch to split this one interface into multiple. This will severely limit achievable throughput/bandwidth. Chances are you wouldn’t be able to use these anyway (no OpenWrt support).

MikroTik publishes benchmarks for most routers, which you could check to find a suitable device.

---

You must make sure the device is connected to your existing network such that no traffic can bypass its CPU. On a typical router, you’d just connect the WAN port to the uplink router (your existing modem/router device) and everything else to the LAN side.

To get what you want you now have to do the following:

- Disable DHCP and the like
- Bridge WAN and LAN in software

Along the way, you must make sure the bridging router is still reachable from the network with an appropriate IP address.

If everything went well, your router should now be bridging traffic between its Ethernet interfaces and your network should basically work as it did before.

You are now ready to set up firewall rules that affect bridged traffic.

---

I haven’t used OpenWrt in years and documentation on this particular subject is severely lacking, to say the least. **Hopefully somebody else can contribute/verify the concrete steps here.**

The [documentation](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/fw3_configurations/bridge) only provides the starting point:

```
opkg update
opkg install kmod-nft-bridge
```

It’s possible to add custom rules in the `/etc/firewall.user` script (regular Linux style). They’d look like this:

```
nft add rule bridge filter forward iif eth1 oif eth2 ether type ip tcp dport 9999 drop
```

Adapt interfaces and protocols, filters as required.

It may also be possible to write the above command using the `nft list ruleset` type syntax, then include it in `/etc/config/firewall` as follows:

```
config include
    option  type        'nftables'
    option  path        '/etc/my_bridge_firewall.nft'
    option  position    'table-post'
```

*Again: This is all unverified.*

---

MikroTik Router OS [supports bridge filtering](https://help.mikrotik.com/docs/display/ROS/Bridging+and+Switching#BridgingandSwitching-BridgeFirewall) too, so no need to install OpenWrt on these devices.

```
/interface bridge filter
add action=drop chain=forward in-interface=ether3 out-interface=ether2 mac-protocol=ip ip-protocol=tcp dst-port=9999 comment="Disallow TCP port 9999"
```

Adapt interfaces and protocols, filters as required. In Winbox and Webfig, you can find these settings at Bridge → Filters. You must select protocols in the order outlined above, some fields will be disabled otherwise.

You can also force bridge traffic to use the “full” IP firewall, using the `use-ip-firewall` setting in a bridge to enabled. It’s probably a lot slower.

Hardware offloading interferes with filters, because the switch chip deals with traffic internally. It should however not apply to bridges between physical interfaces on the CPU/SoC.

Bridge Fast forward may interfere with filters, too, and may have to be disabled.